# Error "Incomplete microdata with schema.org" for Review

Tags: microdata, schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool

I have a product reviews on a site and I am adding Schema.org markup to the reviews. Here is the code I am using:

```html
<div class="blockquote-wrap">
 <blockquote itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review"><span itemprop="reviewBody">Text of the review itself.</span>
<cite><span itemprop="author">Author Name</span>, Location of Author</cite>
</blockquote> 
</div>
```

This is all the reviews are. When I test the page using Google's Structured Data Testing Tool I receive this error:

> Error: Incomplete microdata with schema.org.

My question is what data is missing that is required? I don't see which data is required on the [Schema.org page for reviews](http://schema.org/Review).

Comment: Needs to wrapped in /product or something appropriate.

Comment: As closetnoc commented, you'll need to nest the review under Product: `<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">` and include a name (from the "Microdata" tab under "Examples" in the link you provided): `<span itemprop="name">Kenmore White 17" Microwave</span>`. That should remove the errors, as can be seen [here](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:8004fa5b737e9df1136fac569cebcd31).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because microdata is structured, **Review** must be contained by an object or reference to an object being reviewed, or as the result (associated with an agent) of a ReviewAction. According to the documentation at http://schema.org/Review, instances of Review may appear as *values for* the following properties:

- **resultReview**
- **Organization**
- **Product**
- **CreativeWork**
- **Place**
- **Offer**